# Proper way of sending json response

Tags: ajax, laravel

I used to write in the controller method:

```
echo json_encode(TRUE);die;
```

to pass the success message to the AJAX so that.
e.g.

```
if($user->save())
{
    echo json_encode(TRUE);die;
}
```

and in ajax:

```
 success: function (data) {
            var res = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(res == true)
            {
               alert('user added!');

            }
```

But then i saw most using:
 `return Response::json(TRUE); die;` instead of `echo json_encode(TRUE);die;` what is the difference between these two? Or is it exact similar to echo vs return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just echo text, your response will be sent back the the content type of `plain/html`.

If you return `response()->json()`, then your response will be sent back with the content type of `application/json`.

Some clients may not care one way or another, but others may behave differently if the headers say the response is json. In either case, the `application/json` response is more semantically correct.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to echo the result of a function. For example:

```
function save(){
    //magic happens here
    return $result; //can be false or true (for example)
}
```

and in the file which is called in the ajax request simply put:

```
echo json_encode(save());
```

finally you can compare the result in the client side:

```
success: function(response){
    var result = $.parseJSON(response);
    if(result) alert("Success!");
    else alert("Sorry try later");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done and it's very standard. I have create one helpers.php file and put it in composer.json so no need to further include it in application.

composer.json

```
 "autoload": {
     "files": [
      "app/Utils/helper.php"
    ]
  }
```

run command

```
composer dumpautoload.
```

Create method for success response in helpers.php

```
function success($data, $message, $status = 200, $headers = [])
{
    $result = [];

    $result['flag'] = true;
    $result['message'] = $message;
    $result['data'] = $data;

    return response()->json($result, $status, $headers);
}
```

sending success message from controller.

```
return success($user, 'User logged in successfully.');
```

Create method for error response in helpers.php

```
function error($code, $message, $status = 200, $errors = [], $headers = [])
{
    $error = [];

    $error['flag'] = false;
    $error['message'] = $message;
    $error['code'] = $code;

    if (!empty($errors))
    {
        $error['errors'] = $errors;
    }

    return response()->json($error, $status, $headers);
}
```

sending error message from controller.

```
return error(401, 'These credentials do not match our records.',401);
```